# I try to save a mp3 file on s3 space with python but got empty file

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, gtts

I come here after a few days of research on the subject,
I have a Django class: Question, the admin can create a question: he has to input a "title" and some "items" + True or False for each item. I want to get the "title" of the question as an mp3 file so I use gTTS (google text to speech) and it works as well while I use it locally!

```
 if(sender == Question and kwargs['update_fields'] == None):

    myQuestion = kwargs['instance']
    output = gTTS(myQuestion.title, lang="fr")
    mySound = './media/questionsSound/Question'+str(myQuestion.id)+'.mp3'
    output.save(mySound)
```

Now I want to save these mp3 files on an s3 space because I have many applications that will call them.

So in the first time, I just tried to replace the path of my sound with the path of my bucket but I got this error message :

> [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://[mySpaceName].fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/[myBucketName]/questionSound/Question95.mp3'

This is the first problem that has no sense for me because the URL exists I tried it with files that I dragged and dropped.
So I tried to find a workaround and I decided to save the file in the original folder `./media/questionsSoud...` then to upload it on the s3 space :

```
    import boto3
    from boto3 import session
    from botocore.client import Config
    from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer

    session = session.Session()
    client = session.client('s3', region_name='fra1', endpoint_url=settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    transfer = S3Transfer(client)

    transfer.upload_file(mySound, settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, "testhello.mp3")
    response = client.put_object(ACL='public-read', Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, Key='testhello.mp3')
```

And now the problem is different: I get a file on my space but it is "binary/octet-stream" type instead of "audio/mpeg" and it is absolutely empty (I download it and try it) even if mySound is not empty!

Thank you if you read this big question I would be so grateful if you can help me!

> ** EDIT **

To get a non-empty file I removed the line put_object()
But I still get a "binary/octet" content-type so I found something on GitHub like that for the function upload_file()

```
    mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(mySound)
    print(mimetype)
    if mimetype is None:
        raise Exception("Failed to guess mimetype")
    transfer.upload_file(mySound, settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, "testhello.mp3", ExtraArgs={
            "ContentType": mimetype
        })
```

But I get this error

> upload_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ExtraArgs'

Answer (score 0):

Your `put_object()` command does not specify the data to store, so it is creating a zero-length file. **Try removing your line with `put_object()`** and it should work, because the previous line has probably already uploaded the file.

I'm not familiar with using Digital Ocean, but here's the code you would normally use for S3:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

s3_client.upload_file('./file.mp3', 'mybucket', 'file.mp3', ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read', 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'})
```

Comment: You're right but I added this line to get the file as public, I tried without put_object() but even if I wanted a private file, it stil lis a "binary/octet-stream" content type and I want an "audio/mpeg"

Comment: I have updated the answer to match these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help

For the people who use DigitalOcean too, its finally not a big deal, you can call the url of the "binary/octet-stream" in your front-end application and it's indeed considered as an audio file

Answer (score -1):

it's 'ContentType': 'audio/mp3' not 'Content-Type'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).